# Future Versions in Documentation's Inline Versions

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've already found myself rubbing up against the

```
<!-- if version
```

Structure being overly strict.

I have a feature that I can document as being in a sort of "Pending" state in a future release of Perl ( because I read the mailing list ), and so it makes sense to document that as soon as possible, even if I have to mark it as "pending" or "tentative".

Currently all that happens is I specify the future version I expect it to land in and the stackoverflow Documentation effort tells me its "out of range"

I'd prefer some way, maybe like:

```
  <!-- if future version [gte 5.26]
```

Where the "future" modifier allows numbers above the existing range, but tints the section a different colour (red?) to warn people that "this is going to happen, or it might not, exercise caution".

Then people who are interested in that syntax/feature can *also* see it and go "ooh, neat" and fetch the sources from git or whatever and try the latest version unreleased.

And then when the respective versions are officially added to the version tag list, those sections can be automatically marked for review with regards to currency, and reviewers can either punt the version, delete the section, or downgrade it from a "future" grading.

And before action is taken, versions with the "future" tag where the version range co-incides with the "released" set, the colours get downgraded to yellow saying "This feature was expected in this release, please confirm"

**Footnote**

For Perl things, there are a vastly greater supply of versions than the official matrix could ever support. The matrix wastes space because somebody enumerated all the versions between 1.0 and 5.0, which is never used and you're never going to see people documenting correctly.

( And having to select all applicable versions is a chore, when it would be more appropriate to select a range )

Additionally, there is a desire to be specific about which version a feature really landed in, for instance, the list only states "stable" releases, but for every stable release there are 3-or-4 maintenance releases, and between every stable release is an (unlisted) unstable release with as many as 13 point releases.

Clearly a version tag matrix is going to buckle if we even try enumerate them all, but this limits the accuracy at which we can say new features were added.

e.g: New syntax officially would turn up in 5.25.5 or something, and then the mainstream target of 5.26 can be assumed to include that 95% of the time.

Here it seems like it would be better to allow more free-form versions than require an enumerable set.